# How do I display a histogram in live view on a Nikon D7500?

Tags: nikon, dslr, live-view, histogram

I just bought the Nikon D7500.   I can't find the histogram. How do I get the histogram on my screen? I would like to view it on the live view?

Answer (score 2):

Page 187 of the [*Nikon D7500 User's Manual*](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D7100_EN.pdf):

[image]

If the *Overview* (with luminance histogram) or *RGB histogram* screens are not showing when you cycle through the photo information options, you need to enable them using the *Playback display options* menu covered on page 219.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pressing the info button couple of times to check the different display views, the histogram should be displayed through this button as it is done in other models of Nikon.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but I just figured this out myself.

To get the histogram on **Live View** (Michael C's response is for the *Playback* display):

1. Press the Live View button (Lv),
2. Press the Live View info button (the sort of stylized "i" right next to the Lv button),
3. Scroll to "Exposure preview" and set it to "ON".

Now, when you're in Live View, press the "info" button (the one on the left, with "info" written on it) repeatedly until the live histogram appears.

Hope this can help you or at least other 7500 users!